# pymysql.err.OperationalError - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, connection, operationalerror

I am using Python script to insert records into MySQL database table.
The script fails with the following error message.

***MySQL version is 8.0.17*** ,**Python version  3.6.5**

(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)')

**(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)**

The issue is for only few tables.

[image]

Comment: That's a configuration, server or network issue. Can't say more without details.

Comment: usually when you get that message you run in one of the timeout , so you should start by increasing them.

Comment: Will the timeout  variable settings on MySQL help ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL automatically closes connections that have been idle for a specific period of time (`wait_timeout` for non-interactive connections). Therefore it may happen, that your connections are closed if there is too much idle time and connections are not renewed or connections are invalidated because of server restarts.

[SQL-Alchemy](https://sqlalche.me) mentions several strategies on how to tackle the issue of automatic disconnects and database restarts in its documentation on [how to deal with pool disconnects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#pool-disconnects).

Two options that you should have a look at are the `pool_pre_ping` parameter that adds a `SELECT 1` before each query to check if the connection is still valid, otherwise the connection will be recycled.

The other option is `pool_recycle` time that should always be less then your mysql `wait_timeout`. After this time the connection is automatically recycled to not run in the `wait_timeout`.

You can check your connections in MySQL using the command

```sql
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

where you should see all open connection an the status they are in.

Comment: Can you explain the link in detail?